# ## NULL and ## character (0) appearing in Knit

Tags: r-markdown

I'd like to properly showcase the non-alphanumeric symbols in a dataset column when I knit:

```
dput(fifa21_raw_data$`W/F`[1:20])
```

Output:

```
c("4 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "5 ★", "5 ★", "4 ★", "4 ★", 
"3 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "3 ★", 
"4 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★", "3 ★", "4 ★")
```

The codechunk manages this just fine however, once I knit, the rmarkdown displays ## NULL

Additionally, the code chunk for

```
gsub(" ★"," ", fifa21_raw_data$`W/F`[1:20])
```

output:

```
[1] "4 " "4 " "3 " "5 " "5 " "4 " "4 " "3 " "3 " "4 " "3 "
[12] "4 " "3 " "3 " "4 " "4 " "3 " "4 " "3 " "4 "
```

appears as ## character (0) in the rmarkdown when I knit.

I would very much like to for the rmarkdown to print what is shown in the code chunk if possible. Thank you very much for your efforts! I would also mention that I am very new to this so, if possible, please explain in layman terms!

Comment: Anyone out there with a possible path to a solution?